# How to build a feed for Non Sequitur comics on The Washington Post page?

Tags: rss, feeds, atom

I like this comic: [Non Sequitur](http://wpcomics.washingtonpost.com/client/wpc/nq/) but it has no feed/RSS/Atom.

Is it possible to build one using Yahoo Pipes, YQL or other service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling came up with this...
http://www.arcamax.com/thefunnies/nonsequitur/rss

Comment: Nice, just query for [non sequitur comic feed](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=non+sequitur+comic+feed&qscrl=1)